# How is the abstract 'reads' getting defined?

Tags: json, playframework

In Play, I can create a Reads variable as follows:

```
def checkPassword[T](min:Int): Reads[String] = {
  Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("Invalid username given!"))(str => {
    (str.matches("""[a-z]+""") && (str.length >= min))
  })
}
```

Reads has an abstract `reads` method

```
def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A]
```

How is `reads` getting defined? My best guess would be that there is some `apply` method somewhere which is doing some magic and is making the json:JsValue available to the code in {} as `str`. Am I correct?

Comment: I am guessing but probably the `reads` implementation created by compiler looks as following pseudo code: `reads (json:JsValue):JsResult {  r:JsResult =  json.validate[T]
 r match {
 case s:JsSuccess[T] => (s.get)(Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("Invalid username given!"))(str => {
    (str.matches("""[a-z]+""") && (str.length >= min))
  }))
 case f:JsError =>  
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `Reads` (`checkPassword` return) from another one (`Reads.StringReads`):

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.13/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L773-L781

As you can see, `StringReads` implements the `reads` method. After that, you are using [`filter` method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.13/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L59-L60) which also returns a `Reads`. So, you other words, you are just "transforming" (filtering) an existent `Reads` which already has `def reads` implemented.